# Jmeter generate json payload of request dynamically

Tags: json, scripting, jmeter

I have a Jmeter test plan where I want my HttpSampler to send a post request.

The body of the request should contain Json as follows:

```
{
  "productIds" : [
    "p1",
    "p2",
    ...
  ]
}
```

I have setup a random variable generator that returns well-formed productId with every call. What I would like to do is generating the payload by filling productIds of random pid's taken from the generator, directly in the body of the request. Something like (suppose *** is the scripting escape):

```
{
  "productIds" : [
     ***
       for i in (1, $productsCount) {
         write("\"$randomPid\"\n")
       }
     ***
  ]
}
```

Is it possible? If yes, how? If not, how would you approach the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Add a [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the request you want to parametrize
2. Put following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
   String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
   int max = Integer.parseInt(Parameters);
   Random random = new Random();

   result.append("{");
   result.append("\"productIds\" : [");
   result.append(newline);
   for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
       result.append("\"").append(random.nextInt()).append("\",");
       result.append(newline);
   }
   result.append("]");
   result.append(newline);
   result.append("}");

   vars.put("json", result.toString());
   ```
3. Put your ${productsCount} value into "Parameters" stanza
4. Refer generated payload as `${json}` where required

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more details on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I did it before seeing your answer, was wondering if it was possible to do within the http request payload directly, but this is also ok. Thanks!

Comment: You can use [__Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function right in the request body but the whole approach from coding perspective will be the same

Comment: Official [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) now recommends using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) + Groovy instead of `BeanShell PreProcessor`.