# Is there a way to dynamically set variables values for the post request with jmeter beanshell preprocessor

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell, flowable

I need to dynamically build the following post request JSON body with jmeter beanshell preprocessor. I am referring to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314957/jmeter-generate-json-payload-of-request-dynamically) which has a solution for my problem with looped strings. I would need to do this with json-property(variables) an array of JSON objects with different name and values. Thanks a lot.

```
{
  "processDefinitionId":"optaplannerkey:1:dbc4af8f-7e04-11e9-afa3-1ecac26bb5e0",
  "businessKey":"optaplannerkey",
  "returnVariables":true,
  "variables": [
    {
      "name": "TaskDescription",
      "value": "Fixing the issue with sink"
    },
    {
      "name": "TaskCategory",
      "value": "plumbing"
    },
    {
      "name": "Priority",
      "value": "Medium"
    },
    {
      "name": "Status",
      "value": "New"
    },
    {
      "name": "SkillsRequired",
      "value": "Plumbing Skills"
    },
    {
      "name": "DueDate",
      "value": "2019-05-24T11:23:08.030+05:30"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dummy sampler with the parameterized json request and CSV Data Set Config for the dynamic input. Below, I have paremeterized only two for demo.

[image]
[image]

Then, Use JSR223 Post processor with the following code:-

```
vars.put("responseVar",prev.getResponseDataAsString());
```

This will put response body in "responseVar" variable. Fetch it using ${responseVar}

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot @sunny-teo I did fix the issue with your method of using CSV data set.